# Joomla extension for people posts with categories

Tags: joomla

Are there any type of extensions that let people post what they want with categories. So they need to sign-up and sign-in, and then create a new post, then select the relative category that the post will be shown in to other people. 
I may need to show posts by geo-localisation restriction, for example, posts appears in just US or UK.
I'm a PHP developer. I can achieve this system, but I wondered if it does already exist some CMS like Joomla doing what I need, to save time. I may also be able to develop such Joomla modules if it's allowed. Please need a push around these requirements since I don't have too much experience with Joomla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you use the article section of joomla which is a built in one. I think the things available in joomla package will suit your category, post and signin and signup requirements.

For geo-localisation restrictions I think your php knowledge is more than enough to change or modify few parts of the code in the joomla. I think this way will help you save some time. I have done these before.They have worked fine for me. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Good to know that Vinay. Can I add new text-inputs to the creation form, and drop down selected items for the categories?

Comment: Sure. But follow the joomla style of coding. I have successfully modified the default registration form. I have added many form elements there. Just handle the inputs in the respective pages.

Comment: Thanks a lot Vinay. That saved much time.